# Import bootstrap files with flask

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, netbeans, flask

I'm having trouble importing files to netbeans(IDE) with flask. So far, I have downloaded the bootstrap files and placed them in a folder called "static" (that I created), in the folder where my flask scripts and libraries are kept. On my html page I wrote :. And yes "url_for" was imported.

How can I make this work? For this case and future cases where I need to load different css files. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For importing and using bootstrap you should add them to your `static` folder, i.e.:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{url_for('static', filename='bootstrap.min.css')}}">
  </head>

  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

Please pay attention, that value in `fieldname` should points to Bootsrap's exact name and should include relative path from your `static` folder.

Comment: Does it matter where my static folder is placed?How does my environment even know where the "static" folder is?

Comment: Default your `static` folder is placed in the same folder where you put your running script. And Flask will search it there.

Comment: Ok thanks, I got it working now. I have to create one for every project right? I don't think there's a default one

Comment: @GlebPobudzey Exactly. For each project, and if you use Blueprints - than inside each blueprint folder.